# Match on discriminated union case not contents

Tags: f#, pattern-matching, discriminated-union

Is it possible in F# to match a Discriminated Union based on its case rather than by case contents? For example, if I wanted to filter a list by elements that are of the case `Flag`, is it possible to filter as such? Currently, I am forced to have three separate functions to filter the way I desire. This is the approach I have so far:

```
type Option = 
 {Id : string
  Arg : string}

type Argument =
     | Flag of string
     | Option of Option
     | Unannotated of string

//This is what I'm going for, but it does not work as the "other" match case will never be matched
let LocateByCase (case:Argument) (args : Argument List) =
    args
    |> List.filter (fun x -> match x with
                             | case -> true
                             | _ -> false)

let LocateAllFlags args =
    args
    |> List.filter (fun x -> match x with
                             | Flag y -> true
                             | _ -> false)
let LocateAllOptions args =
    args
    |> List.filter (fun x -> match x with
                             | Option y -> true
                             | _ -> false)

let LocateAllUnannotated args =
    args
    |> List.filter (fun x -> match x with
                             | Unannotated y -> true
                             | _ -> false)
```

Am I missing some facet of the F# language that would make this much easier to deal with?

Comment: Interestingly, this can actually be done very easily from C#, but F# hides the methods that make it easy.  Having said that, rather than `Flag y` you would tend to use `Flag _`

Comment: @JohnPalmer Good point, I will do that in my code from now on. I'm still learning :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no built-in way to find out the case of a DU value. The usual approach, when faced with such requirement, is to provide appropriate functions for each case:

```
type Argument =
     | Flag of string
     | Option of Option
     | Unannotated of string
    with
     static member isFlag = function Flag _ -> true | _ -> false
     static member isOption = function Option _ -> true | _ -> false
     static member isUnannotated = function Unannotated _ -> true | _ -> false

let LocateByCase case args = List.filter case args

let LocateAllFlags args = LocateByCase Argument.isFlag args
```

(needless to say, the `LocateByCase` function is actually redundant, but I decided to keep it in to make the answer clearer)

---

**WARNING: DIRTY HACK BELOW**

Alternatively, you could provide the case as a quotation, and make yourself a function that will analyze that quotation, fish the case name out of it, and compare it to the given value:

```
open FSharp.Quotations

let isCase (case: Expr<'t -> Argument>) (value: Argument) = 
    match case with
    | Patterns.Lambda (_, Patterns.NewUnionCase(case, _)) -> case.Name = value.GetType().Name
    | _ -> false

// Usage:
isCase <@ Flag @> (Unannotated "")  // returns false
isCase <@ Flag @> (Flag "")  // returns true
```

Then use this function to filter:

```
let LocateByCase case args = List.filter (isCase case) args

let LocateAllFlags args = LocateByCase <@ Flag @> args
```

**HOWEVER**, this is essentially a dirty hack. Its dirtiness and hackiness comes from the fact that, because you can't require a certain quotation shape at compile time, it will allow nonsensical programs. For example:

```
isCase <@ fun() -> Flag "abc" @> (Flag "xyz")  // Returns true!
isCase <@ fun() -> let x = "abc" in Flag x @> (Flag "xyz")  // Returns false. WTF?
// And so on...
```

Another gotcha may happen if a future version of the compiler decides to generate quotations slightly differently, and your code won't recognize them and report false negatives all the time.

I would recommend avoiding messing with quotations if at all possible. It may look easy on the surface, but it's really a case of [easy over simple](https://www.infoq.com/presentations/Simple-Made-Easy).

Comment: Fascinating stuff, thank you! Could you explain what the `with static member` bit is? Is that like an Object Method in C#?

Comment: Yes, it's just declaring a static method on your type.

Comment: Since you seem to be a beginner, here is an advice: F# is a very good language. If you find yourself trying to circumvent F#, it is overwhelmingly probable that you have modeled your data incorrectly.